# How to pass multiple objects in IActionResult method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to pass two objects in the `IActionResult` method in Asp.net core. I try the following method but one object pass with the null values. what are the changes should I follow?

```
public IActionResult createService([FromBody] ArmSmServiceCreatorEntity CreateServiceDetail, [FromBody] ArmSmServiceAndSubServiceEntity createSSSDetails)
{
    try
    {
        this.manager.BeginTransaction();

        if (CreateServiceDetail == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Service is null.");
        }

        this.manager.ArmSmServiceCreatorRepository.Add(CreateServiceDetail);

        if (createSSSDetails == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Service is null.");
        }

        this.manager.ArmSmServiceAndSubServiceRepository.Add(createSSSDetails);
        this.manager.Commit();

        return Ok("File was processed.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.manager.Rollback();
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the `json` which you are passing from client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one `FromBody` parameter.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#frombody-attribute) says:

> Don't apply `[FromBody]` to more than one parameter per action method. Once the request stream is read by an input formatter, it's no longer available to be read again for binding other `[FromBody]` parameters.

Use a single object that wraps the two parameters:

```
public class ArmSmServiceRequest {
    ArmSmServiceCreatorEntity CreateServiceDetail { get; set; }
    ArmSmServiceAndSubServiceEntity CreateSSSDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Your method will look like:

```
public IActionResult createService([FromBody] ArmSmServiceRequest)
```

On the client side you also need to wrap two objects into one.